# Get rid of the [howto] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags

Do we really need a [howto](/questions/tagged/howto) tag on SO? I don't think we mean for a question without the tag to be asking how not to do something.

Edit:

Good grief.  There's a [how-to](/questions/tagged/how-to), too

Comment: Agreed. Here's the tag description: "*A how-to is an informal, pithy description of instructions for accomplishing some task. A how-to is usually meant to help non-experts and may be greatly simplified from an in-depth discussion of the topic.*" That's a meta-tag. Kill it with fire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, doesn't look terribly useful to me either. Gone.

[image: tag burninated]

Comment: both of them? Thanks.

Comment: how-to was a synonym of howto.